# Remove duplicates from currentpage parameters

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a custom lookup page where users can associate multiple employees to a inputfield. When user close the lookup it pass the selected employee names to the Main Page through CurrentPage.Parameters method. The problem I am facing is that if user select the name unknowingly for the second time it is creating duplicates on the input field. I tried to assign the targetField.Value to another arry and used to array.filter function to remove the duplicates but unsuccessful. 
[image]

[image]

Lookup Page code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectAllEmployees(){
        var selectedNames = [];
        var selectedIds   = [];
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input:checked'),
        function(v) {
             selectedNames.push(v.dataset.fullName);
             selectedIds.push(v.dataset.emailValue);
         });
         closeAndPassParams(selectedNames,selectedIds);
    }

    function closeAndPassParams(nameTosend,idToSend){
       var parent = window.opener.document;
       var targetField = parent.getElementById('{!$CurrentPage.parameters.namefield}');
       var targetField1 = parent.getElementById('{!$CurrentPage.parameters.idfield}');
       targetField.value = targetField.value + ',' + nameTosend;
       targetField.value = targetField.value.replace(/^,/, '');   //remove the first comma from the array
       targetField1.value = targetField1.value + ','+ idToSend;
       targetField1.value = targetField1.value.replace(/^,/, '');
       self.close();
   }
</script>
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
    <div align="Right" draggable="false">
         <apex:commandButton value="Ok" id="selectEmp" onClick="selectAllEmployees();return false;"/>
         <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="window.top.close()" />
    </div>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `indexOf()` method in JS to check whether the value is already present. Based on that add the value only if it was not added earlier.

*The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.*

```
if(targetField.value.indexOf(nameTosend) == -1) {
    targetField.value = targetField.value + ',' + nameTosend;
}
```